# Kohana's ORM doesn't find my table

Tags: orm, kohana

I have a table named "roles_users" in my database. As well as a model named "roles_users.php" in my application/model folder:

```
<?php

class Model_Roles_users extends ORM {

}
```

I'm trying to create a new row using the following code:

```
$role = ORM::factory('roles_users');
```

However I'm getting an error saying "Class 'Model_Roles_users' not found". It's working with other tables but not this one. Does anybody know why?

Comment: might have something with to do with pluralization. Does the model need to be singular or plural?

Comment: I tried various combinations - 'role_user', 'role_users', 'roles_user' but none of them seems to work. It's always displaying an error "Class 'Model_xx' not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to create models for pivot tables, but rather add rows with something like this:

```
$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name'=>'login')));
```

if you really insist on having a model for that table, it will be Model_Roles_User (model/roles/user.php, having only the last word in it's name singular).

Comment: Well, table name may differs from ORM classname. Use `$_table_name` property in your model to set up custom table name. Just a 2c.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because symbol "_" is used as directory separator, so you cannot use it in file name.

From http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/autoloading:

> Any underscore characters in the class name are converted to slashes